# Alexa Skill Signature validation failing

Tags: c#, .net-core, bouncycastle, alexa-skills-kit

I can't get the signature verification working, like it's described [here](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/developing-an-alexa-skill-as-a-web-service#checking-the-signature-of-the-request). I'm using [BouncyCastle.NetCore 1.8.1.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BouncyCastle.NetCore/) and the project is a .NETCoreApp 1.0.

I'm developing on macOS 10.12.1, running dotnet core 1.0.4 and my server is running Ubuntu 16.04.2-x64 running the release version, build as netcore1.0 and ubuntu16.04-x64 app.

The rest of the system runs without problems, except the signature verification.

My validation always returns **false**.

Here is my service for validating the signature and body:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MySkill.Main.Services
{
    public class CertificationValidationService : ICertificationValidationService
    {
        private const string Algorithm = "SHA1withRSA";

        public async Task<bool> IsValidSiganture(Stream body, Stream certData, string signature)
        {
            var pemReader = new Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemReader(new StreamReader(certData));
            var cert = (Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate)pemReader.ReadObject();

            using (var sr = new StreamReader(body))
            {
                var content = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
                var result = CheckRequestSignature(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content), signature, cert);

                return result;
            }
        }

        private static bool CheckRequestSignature(byte[] bodyData, string signature, Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate cert)
        {
            byte[] sig = Convert.FromBase64String(signature);

            var pubKey = (Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.RsaKeyParameters)cert.GetPublicKey();
            var signer = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.SignerUtilities.GetSigner(Algorithm);
            signer.Init(false, pubKey);
            signer.BlockUpdate(bodyData, 0, bodyData.Length);

            return signer.VerifySignature(sig);
        }
    }
}
```

Does anybody have a tip, what i'm doing wrong or has used a different framework or apis?

Comment: 1. Are you sure about the "content" being encoded in UTF8?
2. Did you try a different algorithm?

Comment: 1. Yes, the content is UTF8 for sure. 2. I tried the System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates classes. but it's also not working. It's crashing dotnet.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you shared it looks correct. Without seeing the rest of the code I am not sure if the Signature you got is correct. You can take a look at our C# code that passed certification at https://github.com/sophtron/Alexa-Skill-Sophtron and compare against your own to see if there are any differences.

I tried RSACryptoServiceProvider from .net library for signature validation and it had never worked. So I had to switch to BouncyCastle.1.8.1 too and it worked for me.